# How long should we wait to flag Low-Quality on barely acceptable answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality

Inspired by [this answer](https://superuser.com/revisions/1214292/1)

This answer does seem attempt to answer the question, but is unfinished when posted (although it did got edited after I reminded the author).

Left as is, the question will fall to Very Low-quality, which is unsalvageable. However, it might get edited if we remind the author (as he did in this case).

**Q:** How long reasonably should we wait before flagging it? 1 hour? 24 hour? Or should we down-vote and retract it after edit was made?

Comment: It appears in later revisions the OP has fixed their answer..

Comment: @Burgi yep, that's why I linked on the original revision, not the answer itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Immediately. Waiting makes no sense, especially when the quality of the answer isn't that great as is

Mods can always comment, delete, and undelete once the post is edited to completion.

Comment: You can edit your deleted question? That's new for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Vylix - The author of the answer can modify their answer if its deleted.  A moderator can undelete an answer until its purged from the system.  Users with I believe 10k reputation can see deleted answers, and they can vote to undelete, once the answer is modified.

Comment: And any user can see their own posts - even if its an answer to a deleted question, if they know where it is. And if a mod comments on a question shortly before or after deletion, it will turn up in their inbox so they can find it

Comment: Users with 10K can see deleted questions and answers, but you have to know where to look. We can vote to delete and undelete questions, but not answers, except in the context of the Low Quality Posts review queue, where users with 2K can recommend deletion of flagged answers.

Comment: The idea is the if a question is *that* bad, OP probably should be the one to fix it. and by commenting, the user will know what's wrong.